# IntelliJ Scala Project Issue from version control

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, intellij-scala

I have imported Scala project from the Version control (Git). In the build.sbt not recognizing name, version control etc. In the assembly.sbt below line is not recognizing.

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.6")

I tried couple of things added language support for Scala, enable auto import etc but still no luck. In the build.sbt i don't see sbt in the right side of panel as shown in the picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyRzo.png)

Below is different project where I can see sbt support in the project.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you opened the project as an sbt project?

Comment: Can you make a gif of how you open the project?

Comment: I have a empty git project and which i opened in the intellij, File -> New -> Proejct From Version Control. Now my question is how to enable sbt support in that project.

Comment: Can you try adding `resolvers += Resolver.bintrayIvyRepo("com.eed3si9n", "sbt-plugins")` to `assembly.sbt` file?